# How to run R shiny app by clicking on file without opening mac's terminal

Tags: r, macos, terminal, shiny

I have coded an app with R and Shiny. I have also created the file with the code below so that the app runs when I double click on the app file.

```
cd ~/Dropbox\ \(Centeo\ ApS\)/0.Raportering/
R -e "shiny::runApp('ignore.R', launch.browser=TRUE)"
```

Everything so far works perfectly.

The only issue I have is that, when I double click on the app file to run the app, the Mac's terminal opens and stays open til I close the app.

So my question is: is there a way I can modify the code above so that the terminal windows does not open?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try to create a launch daemon instead https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPSystemStartup/Chapters/CreatingLaunchdJobs.html

Comment: thanks for your answer Pork Chop. That definitely looks like something I can look into. But do you know if there is an easier way around? Thanks in advance!

Comment: `runApp` has `quiet = FALSE,` set that to `TRUE` and try it again